# Nav Bar Transparent on Homepage Only (Php and CCS)

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make the navbar of the "homepage" transparent so the background can be seen while the other pages stay the same with a non-transparent navbar, I do not know which direction to take when editing the php to add category pages so I can edit transparency in of the homepage nav. Where do I edit in php? I hope someone can help me.

here's the CCS:

```
* Top menu
*/
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner, .navbar-static-top .navbar-inner {
    box-shadow: none;
    }
.navbar {

}
.navbar-inner {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    filter: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    /*-webkit-transition: all .6s;
    transition: all .6s;*/
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar .brand {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar .nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar .nav > .active > a, 
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus {
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    color: #717171;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-bottom: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s;
    transition: all .6s;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
.navbar .nav > li:last-child > a {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar .nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-collapse.collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar .btn-navbar {
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500
    text-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    filter: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar .btn-navbar .title {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.navbar .btn-navbar .icon-bar {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #26cdb3;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar .btn-navbar:hover,
.navbar .btn-navbar:focus,
.navbar .btn-navbar:active,
.navbar .btn-navbar.active,
.navbar .btn-navbar.disabled,
.navbar .btn-navbar[disabled] {
    color: #26cdb3;
    background: transparent;
}
/**
```

The header PHP is this (im not sure is i should edit the header PHP though

```
<?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>  
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top clearfix">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container"> <a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>" alt=""></a> 
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <div class="pull-left"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </div>
        <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'fencer' ); ?></span> </a>
        <?php
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML/PHP code as well so we can see how the header is formatted?

Comment: Can you just edit your original post and put in a code format like you did with your CSS or jfiddle?

Comment: sorry for that..i placed it on the original post.

Comment: Are you using an `include("header.php")` on all pages or is each one adding the header separately?

Comment: sorry just saw this now. yes it's a general header.php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after looking at the site this is the easiest way to fix the problem.

First create a class in CSS that has a transparent background instead of the current black background.

```
.navbar-inner-home{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Now in your **index.php** file change the header's

```
<div class="navbar-inner" style="transition: all 0.6s; -webkit-transition: all 0.6s; padding: 25px 0px 15px;">
```

to

```
<div class="navbar-inner-home" style="transition: all 0.6s; -webkit-transition: all 0.6s; padding: 25px 0px 15px;">
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean transparent and not hidden because if you had it hidden you could never navigate to another page.

Comment: yes, transparent only. i will try! and share results in a minute. thank you :)

Comment: I tried setting the navbar-inner to navbar inner home..but it makes all the nav bar in other pages go transparent. (this was done in header php) I cannot see a way to edit the index.php files.

Comment: I tried adding another div class for navbar inner home, but it doubles the navbar.

Comment: the header.php is general. although I am using a specific page design which has it's own .php but I checked, the it calls for the header.php..

Comment: What you can do is copy/paste the header onto the index page (instead of doing an `include` and change the value. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PHP before, but I assume you can set CSS styles with it. Can't you just set the visibility property of the navbar to hidden when the homepage is loaded, then set it back when someone leaves the homepage?

```
    .navbar
    {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
```

or something similar

Comment: i tried that but the editing is general..it's across all the pages.

Comment: @myk930 Does PHP have OnLoad functions for pages? So when the homepage is loaded you can make it hidden, and when every other page is loaded it makes it visible?

Comment: @myk930 Does it have to be with PHP, could you use javascript instead?

Comment: no onload functions..i checked. it is based on php :)

Comment: @myk930 Did you end up getting your answer, or are you still looking?

Comment: i am still looking :)

Comment: @myk930 Does homepage have a seperate html page, or does your website fill a div with content from other pages?

Comment: I checked again and I found out I am using a separate php file for the page..but header still comes from header.php

Comment: @myk930 in HTML you can go `<body onload="function" onunload="function">` Use these, and make the header transparent when the homepage page is loaded, and non transparent when it is unloaded.